# nodejs: Unexpected token "<"

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

I have a piece of code like this:

```js
var i = 10;
if (i < 0 || i => 10) {
  console.log("Out of bounds!");
}
```

But nodejs throws the following error:

```
if (i < 0 || i => 10) { console.log("Out of bounds!"); }
      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Comment: It's throwing a different error in the browser

Comment: The `=>` should be `>=`. `=>`defines an arrow function...

Comment: This is an error that took me 10 minutes to fix, because the difference between "=>" and ">=" is a bit hard to understand, and because the error message points to a different place in the code. That is why I added this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the `<`, but the `=>` in the second comparison. This is not the greater-or-equal comparison operator, but the arrow operator for defining functions.
This confuses nodejs, and it throws the error.

Please use `>=` instead:

```
if (i < 0 || i >= 10) { console.log("Out of bounds!"); }
```